# How to update content in android app efficiently

Tags: android

I am developing an android application, in which I have to fetch data from a remote server.To reduce fetching time, I want to store data locally and to update it whenever the data at server is updated.

I want to know how I can update my local storage so my app can work efficiently.I have to update my local storage in two cases.

1. When new row is inserted in server data-base
2. When existing row is updated

In both cases, my local storage should be updated. I want to fetch only updated row and inserted row instead of whole data.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this, [SyncAdapters](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) and how to [Create a Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

It should explain the ways to achieve what you are looking for.